# Looking to remap side buttons on Logitech Marble to scroll -- how is this done?

Tags: mouse, logitech

I've seen threads and responses similar to this, but I'll note that I'm super inexperienced with coding and linux in general so I'm not able to follow things that clearly.

The Logitech marble has two additional buttons on the side of the left and right click. I want to remap these to scroll up and down, so I can just click the button and it'll scroll a bit down the page. I have a keyboard that is programmable and was able to do this with some of the keys, but no idea how to do it with the mouse.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the most comprehensive tutorial for configuring the buttons on the Logitech Trackman Marble.  Hope this helps.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Logitech_Marblemouse_USB